# cfpdf merge error when trying to merge multiple pdf files

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, adobe, coldfusion-9, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using CFPDF to merge multiple PDFs together.  The PDFs were created using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1.  In most cases the code works fine, but 2 of my documents error whenever merged together.  My online searches came up empty and I'm really at a loss.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<cfpdf action="merge" destination="#outputFile#" overwrite="yes">
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(pdfFiles)#">
        <cfpdfparam source="#pdfFiles[i]#">
    </cfloop>
</cfpdf>
```

The error occurs on line 173

```
<cfpdfparam source="#pdfFiles[i]#">
```

cfcatch.message

```
 com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.types.ASString cannot be cast to [B
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.types.ASString cannot be cast to [B
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.interchange.structure.StructureUtil.calculateSuffix(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.impl.PMMNamedDestinations.getNewDestName(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.impl.PMMNamedDestinations.cloneNamedDestination(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.impl.PMMNamedDestinations.cloneDestination(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMBookmark$AppendBookmark.cloneBookmark(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMBookmark$AppendBookmark.firstAction(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMBookmark.walkBookmarksTree(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMBookmark.walkBookmarksTree(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMBookmark.appendBookmarks(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMService.insertPagesinRange(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.services.manipulations.PMMService.appendPages(Unknown Source)
at coldfusion.pdf.PDFDocOperation.merge(PDFDocOperation.java:435)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.PDFParamTag.doStartTag(PDFParamTag.java:196)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
at cfcombineDocs2ecfm834801932.runPage(D:\inetpub\wwwroot\BUSINESS_APPS\rmsouf\docs\combineDocs.cfm:173)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
at cfapplication2ecfc1314889339$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(D:\inetpub\wwwroot\BUSINESS_APPS\rmsouf\application.cfc:155)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:280)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:356)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: How do these 2 documents differ from the working ones?

Comment: There seems to be no discernible difference between the 2 that won't print.  All documents contain text and images.  And the 2 that won't print together will print with others.  I'm baffled.

Comment: So merging only these two documents (without any further documents) throws the error? Can you recreate the documents in doubt just to make sure they are not damaged?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same thing with ColdFusion versions 9 and 10, when trying to merge two PDFs (one portrait and one landscape) created with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I was able to tinker with the markup generating those PDFs and the merge seemed to bomb whenever my second PDF had any heading tags (h1-6). It seems this has something to do with the "bookmarks" wkhtmltopdf creates out of heading tags.

[cfpdf](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfpdf.html) accepts an optional boolean attribute keepBookmark, when merging. Adobe documentation *claims* this:

> Specifies whether bookmarks from the source PDF documents are retained in the merged document

Instead, I find it retains any bookmarks from the first PDF and discards those from the second, but close enough I guess...

I added this parameter to my merge call and it stopped throwing that exception:

```
var pdfMerger = new PDF();
pdfMerger.addParam(source="xyzzy");
var combinedPDF = pdfMerger.merge(name="combinedPDF", keepBookmark=false);
```

I haven't tested this in CFML, but it would be

```
<cfpdf action="merge" destination="#outputFile#" overwrite="yes" keeyBookmark="no">
...
</cfpdf>
```

A workaround for me, not really a solution.

Comment: just wanted to say that this fix worked for me as well, ACF 10.  Same problem, multiple files generated with wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue using CF10. (Not tested in CF11 or 2016.) No amount of tweaking ColdFusion/Java settings would enable CF to merge a very simple, small PDF generated using [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) even though isPDFFile() = true and CFPDF "Optimize" worked.

I reverted to using CFExecute with [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) (GNU General Public License (GPL) Version 2). In addition to working with a wider variety of PDFs, it merges faster, has similar features (compress, watermark, rotate, encrypt) and advanced features (metrics, file attachments, generate FDF Data Stencils, Repair Corrupted PDF, etc).

Here's the command line syntax to merge various PDFs into a single file.

**Please note:** File paths & names cannot contain spaces.  PDFs must be filenames and not stored in RAM as a named variable.

```
<cfscript>
PDFs = [
    "c:\CFDocument.pdf",
    "c:\WKHTMLTOPDF.pdf",
    "c:\MSWord.pdf",
    "c:\PDFForge.pdf",
    "c:\ActivePDF.pdf"
];
MergedPDF = "c:\PDFtk_merged.pdf";
Args = "#ArrayToList(PDFS, ' ')# cat output #MergedPDF# dont_ask";
</cfscript>

<cfexecute name="c:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" arguments="#args#" timeOut="60"></cfexecute>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue with adobe pdfs. The problem was the form fields were set to `format = numeric` but I was passing in strings. Removing the formatting fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around this is to use the processDDX action in cfpdf with a DDX that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DDX xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/ coldfusion_ddx.xsd">
<PDF result="Out1">
<PDF source="Doc1"/>
<PDF source="Doc2"/>
</PDF>
</DDX>
```