# CFPDF merge error: Error casting an object of type com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.types.ASString cannot be cast to [B to an incompatible type

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfpdf, cfthread

I am trying to merge a series of pdf files I have created with cfthread. I am using the following code:

```
<cfquery name="data">
select * from mytable
</cfquery>
<cfset threadList = "">
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#data.recordcount#"> 
    <cfset name = "threadnumber#x#"> 
    <cfset threadList = listAppend(threadList,name)>
    <cfthread name="#name#">
        <cfloop query="data">
            <cfpdf action="read" name="myPDF#randrange(1,1000)#" source="#Expandpath('/_pdf/#data.cusip#.pdf')#" />
        </cfloop>
    </cfthread> 
</cfloop>
<cfthread action="join" name="#threadlist#" />  

<cfpdf action="merge" name="final">
    <cfloop list="#threadlist#" index="i">
        <cfloop query="data"> 
            <cfpdfparam source="#Expandpath('/_pdf/#data.cusip#.pdf')#">
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop> 
</cfpdf>
```

However, I am getting errors like this:

```
Error casting an object of type com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.types.ASString cannot be cast to [B to an incompatible type. This usually indicates a programming error in Java, although it could also mean you have tried to use a foreign object in a different way than it was designed.
com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.types.ASString cannot be cast to [B


The error occurred in D:/inetpub/wwwroot/project1/schedulefocuslist.cfm: line 77
75 :    <cfloop list="#threadlist#" index="i">
76 :        <cfloop query="data"> 
77 :            <cfpdfparam source="#Expandpath('/_pdf/#data.cusip#.pdf')#">
78 :        </cfloop>
79 :    </cfloop>
```

Comment: When if doubt, look at your data.  Forget the pdf stuff for now and run the final loop outputting all relevant variables.

Comment: I don't understand what the first part with cfthread does. The problem was mentioned before but not solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616020/cfpdf-merge-error-when-trying-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files Are the files read? Does ExpandPath do what you expect?

Comment: yes expandpath i am getting the correct file from it, even though @dan: i am able to fully get the data values returned by the pdf and read by too

Comment: Are both files PDFs?  use IsPDFFile() to determine if they are "Adobe compatible" as I've had some issues and CF refused to acknowledge the file as a valid PDF file. You may want to add a check for FileExists() in case the PDF file didn't actually get generated (and then throw a different error or something.) Maybe try setting the source attribute to an assigned variable (theFile="#Expandpath('/_pdf/#data.cusip#.pdf')#"... <cfpdfparam source="#TheFile#") as CF sometimes has weird issues w/dynamic evaluation in some built-in functions.

Comment: i forgot to tell, i m generating pdf using wkhtmltopdf, so is that could be the reason, if yes, how can i solve it

Comment: If you believe the problem is with the files themselves, isolate that from the rest of your application.  Write a simple page that reads and merges two files.  Once you have that working, put the solution into your app.

Comment: i suspect that it could be an issue, but i do not know thhe solution to it

Comment: I just encountered this issue personally using CF10. CF10's isPDFFile() says "yes", but CFPDF Merge says "abort".   I found that this was posted 10 months earlier here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616020/cfpdf-merge-error-when-trying-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: CFPDF "optimize" works too... but the optimized PDF cannot be merged either.